# Detect a written date/event in a text in Swift 3

Tags: date, swift3, textview, uilabel

I'm making a chat app and would like it to behave like the apple mail app; that means that it recognizes written dates and underlines them. 
Example: if I write an email that contains: "Would you like to meet on Friday at 4pm?" it should automatically recognize and underline "Friday at 4pm" and when I tap on it is asks me to make a reminder for this event.

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything on that by googling so I can't provide any sample code; still hope someone has experience with that.

Comment: You should check the date detecting ability of `NSDataDetector`.

Comment: Thanks! That did help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code refer from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-detect-a-url-in-a-string-using-nsdatadetector):-

```
let input = "This is your date 2017-02-02"
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue)
guard let matches = detector?.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))
else {return}
for match in matches {
    let date = (input as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
    print(date)
}
```

Comment: This is for checking links and not dates.

Comment: Note that the code has been updated for dates, previous comment is thus invalid now.